# Class helper function alternative

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net

**Jobs Table**
JobID (int, autonumber),
Name (varchar),
Foreman (int) – Contains EmpID from Employee table
…

**Employee Table**
EmpID (int, autonumber),
FirstName (varchar),
LastName (varchar),
…

Using VB.NET

My Job class has properties for all the columns in the Jobs table and methods to load them from the sql database and to persist them to the database.

However, when I instantiate a Job object I would like it to have a readonly foreman name property, but I don’t know how to do that properly using OOP.  I am currently relying on shared helper functions. It seems like there must be a better way.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sub classing my FWO class and adding the additional property there.
This example involves having a foreman name property associated with a field work order (FWO) when the FWO table contains just the employee row ID value. Basically the same issue as the foreman for a job in my initial question.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class FWOWrk
    Inherits FWO

    Private mForemanName As String

    ReadOnly Property ForemanName() As String
        Get
            Return mForemanName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(sConnStr As String, FWOID As Int32)
        ' Constructor

        ' Call FWO.New
        MyBase.New()
        MyBase.ConnectString = sConnStr

        MyBase.GetByID(FWOID)

        ' Get employee info for foreman.
        GetForeman()

    End Sub

    Private Sub GetForeman()
        ' Get the foreman and load the mForeman name property.
        Dim oEmp As New Emp
        oEmp.ConnectString = MyBase.ConnectString
        oEmp.GetByPKey(MyBase.Co, MyBase.Foreman)
        mForemanName = oEmp.FirstName & " " & oEmp.LastName

        oEmp = Nothing

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public virtual Employee ForemanDetail
{
    get
    {
        return Enumeration.FromValue<Employee>(Foreman);
    }
    private set {}
}
```

This doesn't set the Foreman name but does give you access to the details as required. The syntax might be slightly wrong but it should at least send you in the right direction.